# html - why there is some extra space between LI tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a list of image by using `<li>` tag, but I found that there is some extra space between each `<li>` tag.

Just see http://jsfiddle.net/scarletsky/VKCs5/

I just want to know why there is extra space between `<li>` tag, and how to fix it.

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's not the `li`s causing this problem but the images. images are inline-elements with `vertical-align: baseline` by default, so you'll have to set them to `vertical-align: bottom` or `diaplay_block` to solve this:

```
li img {
    border: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VKCs5/3/

Comment: It was ok in your case. But if you see it clearly the Image was occupying only 200px height but the li is occupying some extra 5px. I wanted to know where the extra 5 pixels are wasting?

Comment: Yes, I want to know too. As @Lakshmi Prasanna mention, with the Chrome Dev Tools, I found the image's height is 200px, but the `LI`'s height is 202px. This extra space is really confusing me.

Comment: these extra pixel are the space reserverd for the descenders of the font used in the `li` (so, in fact, there's a third way to solve this problem: set `font-size: 0` - but thats really ugly). for a longer explanation just read about how vertical-align works - http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/ is a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

Because your images are displayed inline, ie. on the same line as text would be, you get white gaps underneath to allow space for descenders from the text. Consider if you had a `y` or a `g` on the same line - it needs space underneath.

You can fix this by making the image `display: block;` or `vertical-align: bottom;`

Comment: Just setting `img { vertical-align: middle; }` is just fine. No need for display as block.

Answer (score 1):

just setting the `display: block;` to your image will avoid the space [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKCs5/4/)

---

images are initially inline or inline-block by default so you need to consider it by assigning it to block.

---

Any element with display inline or inline-block has about 4 pixel space by default between them [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6D4pC/)

so the images are inline or inline-block by default and it will contain the space obviously.

---

So, to avoid the space for the elements you should use float instead. For the elements in this case too, you can use `float: left;` [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VKCs5/5/)

Thus, main reason is that having inline or inline-block display is causing the space.

Comment: We can achieve this in many ways. But I wanted to know why there is 5 pixels padding for every li even the padding was fixed to zero?

Comment: images with display inline is causing the space but not with padding values of li

Comment: But why the `display: inline` will cause extra spacing ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vertical space, not a nbsp due to the whitespace in between `li`s.

You can fix it by changing the vertical alignment of the images, which I have set to bottom instead of its default of baseline.

```
li img {
    border: none;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VKCs5/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS

```
li img {
    border: medium none;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`ul li` have some space by default to remove that add the code :

```
ul,li{
padding:0;
margin:0
}
```

or you can use [CSS RESET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) :

Comment: He does have a reset added to his fiddle.

Comment: this isn't the problem here, the example doesn't have padding or margin added on `li`s